# Convert class variables to object

Tags: class, flutter, dart, save

I am writing my application in dart.

I have a class like this

```
class AuthUser {
  String token = "";
  DateTime expiryDate;
  String userId = "";
  String username = "";
  String firstName = "";
  String lastName = "";
}
```

I set these values in various stages of the application.
I want to save this data after user has log in.

Is there a way to get object of key values from this class like this

```
{
'token':'1131313131',
'expiryDate': '89080',
'userId':5,
'username:'abc',
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add such a function to your `AuthUser` class:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => 
  {
    'token': token,
    'expiryDate': expiryDate,
    'userId': userId,
    'username': username,
  };
```

Then invoke it when you want to get JSON data representation.

Finally, use `jsonEncode()` function to get `String` representation:

```
var json = jsonEncode(week.toJson());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this utility. It will include your request :) 
Awesome

https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

```
class AuthUser {
  String token;
  String expiryDate;
  int userId;
  String username;

  AuthUser({this.token, this.expiryDate, this.userId, this.username});

  AuthUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    token = json['token'];
    expiryDate = json['expiryDate'];
    userId = json['userId'];
    username = json['username'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['token'] = this.token;
    data['expiryDate'] = this.expiryDate;
    data['userId'] = this.userId;
    data['username'] = this.username;
    return data;
  }
}
```